# Подключить сетевой каталог

Tags: linux

Стоит у меня Dr. Web на рабочей машине ubuntu, хочу проверить файлы на рабочем сервере debian 7, как мне к нему подключиться? смонитровать сетевую папку, что бы DW увидел этот каталог.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предположим, что доступ к серверу есть, а это значит, что есть доступ по ssh. Если его нет, лучше его получить.

Создайте где-нибудь (например, в домашнем каталоге) папку, пусть это будет "share". Потом в консоли пишите

```
sshfs [user@]host:[dir] ~/share
```

`[user@]host` Вы должны знать, иначе как к серверу подключаетесь. dir - каталог для проверки. просто `/` указывать крайне не рекомендую.

Может так случится, что sshfs нет, тогда его всегда можно доставить - `apt install sshfs`.

Все, теперь просто проверяете папку как обычную.

- **NB1:** если подключение к серверу не по локалке (а к примеру сервер где то далеко), будет сильно тупить.
- **NB2:** лучше снести антивирь с  рабочей машины - он скорее всего бессмысленный.
- **NB3:** для проверки серверов есть другие способы (в зависимости от провеямого материала).

Если вдруг нет доступа, нужно добавить себя в группу fuse

```
sudo usermod -aG fuse <username>
```

Comment: Не выходит просмотреть папку, You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of “share”.

Comment: я не знаю, какой каталог Вы подключили и есть ли права на его просмотр.

Comment: домашний каталог, там все права есть, на папку share показывает права, d?????????  ? ?    ?           ?              ? share
Хотя указал её в антивирусе, он без проблем начал проверять

Comment: попробуйте открыть эту папку от рута.